# Basic example of RTSP requests

Tags: rtsp

Can I get a sample for sending RTSP requests to a server? My application requires streaming live data. I need to start with a very basic example to implement RTSP requests.

Comment: check out sample applications at http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/